# how user agent in network conditions tab works

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-dev-editor

This is the screenshot of `network conditions` tab in google chrome. It allows you to set browser specs.

[image]

I am wondering, how is this done? It surely doesn't change navigator object directly, since it is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the [setUserAgentOverride](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/Network/#method-setUserAgentOverride) method of the [debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol). Chrome then handles that value internally.

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to access Chrome Debugging Protocol from terminal/command line?

Comment: @sanjihan What do you want to do? You can access it inside a Chrome Extension, but that would mean you can't use the normal DevTools at the same time. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger You can also enable remote debugging and access it from outside Chrome. If you just want to have a look and play around with it you can follow this Contributing to Chrome guide https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNF-KqRSzPLUUfZqQG5AFeU_Ll8TfWYcJasa_XGf7ro/edit#

Comment: I wanted to change the user agent.  Not just for the current opened tab. Preferably from code. I imagined it would be the easiest if I could do the same as Dev Tools do.

Comment: I think there are Chrome Extensions that can do that for you. Looks like it's possible using `chrome.webRequest` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: Since I am not really used to writing extensions, is it possible to do that from  terminal/command line?

Comment: There are a bunch of existing Chrome extensions that look like they would be useful. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/user%20agent?_category=extensions If you prefer another solution you could look into tunneling all traffic through a proxy.

Comment: Yes, I will thank you.Although proxies are little useful when someone is fingerprinting your browser